# How to count distinct value count in pandas using condition?

Tags: python, pandas

My Dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
{
    'BusId':['ABC1','ABC2','ABC2','ABC4'],
    'Route':[101,102,102,104]
})
df
```

I need to list only distinct values in the output for column route

Expected Output:

```
    BusId   Route
0   ABC1    101
1   ABC2    102
3   ABC4    104
```

Comment: Maybe the context is different here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#if test all columns for dupes
#df = df.drop_duplicates()
#if multiple columns and need specify columns for test
df = df.drop_duplicates(['BusId','Route'])
print (df)
  BusId  Route
0  ABC1    101
1  ABC2    102
3  ABC4    104
```

Comment: It works thanks please upvote the question.